# How to check if VMHost is configured with Syslog forwarding

Tags: powershell, vmware, powershell-4.0, powercli, vcenter

I want to check if VMHost is configured with Syslog forwarding

I have written the following cmdlets but it is not giving "Syslog forwarding" status.

```
$esxcli = Get-EsxCli -VMHost abc.com
$esxcli.system.syslog | Select-Object *
```

`$esxcli.system.syslog | gm` is returning an error

```
gm : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
At line:1 char:25
+ $esxcli.system.syslog | gm
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand
```

`$esxcli.system.syslog.config.get()` is returning an error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $esxcli.system.syslog.config.get()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: thanks...this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerCLI includes the [`Get-VMHostSysLogServer`](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Get-VMHostSysLogServer.html) cmdlet. In the context of your question, this command would return the Syslog Server for the VMHost abc.com:

```
Get-VMHostSysLogServer -VMHost abc.com
```